# getting group info of a user

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I want to extract the groups where a particular user is member.How can I extract group information of a user.I tried using restfb and facebook4j but I think it's not possible through that. So I am not sure also about whether I can access a particular user's group information ie for which all groups that user belongs. Any help will be appreciated